# Solving a trignonometric equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

I am trying to find the points where a parametric curve meets itself.

$$x= -\frac{2}{\pi} + \cos t \text{ and }  y = -\frac{2t}{\pi} + \sin t,
\text{  where } t\in (-\pi, \pi).$$

Asuming $t, s$ are such that the curve meets itsef from $x(t)= x(s)$ I get $t=-s$ substituting in 2, I arrive to $2t = \pi \sin t$.

No there I am stuck, can I get a hint

Comment: Did you notice that this is the equation of a circle ?

Comment: It's not a circle because of the second t in y(t).

Comment: what about the curve cutting itself at  $x = -2/\pi, y = 0$ for $t = \pm \pi/2?$